# AppFabric Cache Object GET times too long

Tags: appfabric

I have installed Windows server AppFabric Cache in a development machine (Windows 7) to try it. I have created a simple aspx page which GETs a DataTabel (1000 rows integer and string) that I have saved earlier in the Cache. Calculating the GET times (I used Stopwatch class) after a sequense of page reloads I got the following times 13ms, 13ms, 13ms, 13ms, 439ms, 13ms, 309ms, 452ms, 603ms, 195ms, 565ms, 13ms, etc. I am totally comfused with that and I cannot explain it. What might cause such a delay considering that 13ms is the normal time?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed any bottlenecks (CPU, memory, network) during the test?
Try to compare with queries to persistent database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I think the  answer is in this article http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/07/reaching-stable-performance-in-appfabric-cache-with-a-non-idle-cache-channel/